# PHP in built OR User defined function for passwords in MySQL

Tags: php, encryption

By seeing [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46770463/login-system-in-php-by-username-or-phone?noredirect=1#comment80486234_46770463) and commenting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46770463/login-system-in-php-by-username-or-phone?noredirect=1#comment80520277_46770463), a question raised in my mind, that why we don't use our own `PHP` function for securing the passwords in `MySQL`?

It is said that encrypting passwords is not a good idea, instead, we should use **PHP in-built functions**. Like [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) & [password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

What if I make my own **PHP Function**?

For example:

The secure code for `HI HOW ARE YOU?` should be `zq1zag1ewn1:a>!`

I used `array` in the function.

The code goes like:

```
$txt = "HI HOW ARE YOU?";
$trans = array(" " => "1", "H" => "z", "C" => "f", "I" => "q", "O" => "a", "W" => "g", "A" => "e", "R" => "w", "E" => "n", "Y" => ":", "U" => ">", "?" => "!");
  $change = strtr($txt, $trans);
  echo $change;
```

Can I get reasons for using `PHP in-built function` instead of my function?

Comment: The built-in functions are created for real-world use and running good encryption algorythms. Your own encryption function may lack of these very important features

Comment: If you make your own function to encrypt passwords, then you'll be writing something that is probably highly insecure.... witness the fact that you're  talking about encrypting rather than hashing, showing that you don't know enough about security to understand the difference

Comment: As for your example code, a simple substitution cipher can be broken in seconds; not even as secure as Napoleon's Vignere ciphers

Comment: When saving a password verifier just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Better yet use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt`, `passlib.hash` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a substantial of time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I get reasons for using PHP in-built function instead of my function?

Your approach is horribly insecure, and would've been broken by even WWII-era codebreakers working by hand - probably using something like [frequency analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_analysis). Hell, [the ancient Romans <sup><sub>(possibly even earlier, but they're the earliest documented)</sub></sup> invented your fundamental technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher).

This is why you don't [roll your own crypto](https://motherboard.vice.com/en_us/article/wnx8nq/why-you-dont-roll-your-own-crypto). You're likely to screw it up. You've just demonstrated how easy it is to write something that seems secure to you, but could be broken in milliseconds by any modern computer.

**If you are not a team of expert cryptologists, your solution is probably not as good as the decades-old, tested, peer-reviewed solutions from *actual* teams of expert cryptologists.**

See also:

- [Why passwords should be hashed](http://security.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/why-passwords-should-be-hashed/)
- [Why shouldn't we roll our own?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/18197/7685)
- [How to securely hash passwords](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords)

Comment: (In addition, a simple webserver misconfiguration might expose your PHP code, which would give an attacker the means to decrypt all passwords. With hashing, a source code compromise *does not* give this ability.)

Comment: Which one is best `password_hash()` OR `password_verify()`?

Comment: @Chiru You need both, they do different things. Read the docs.